# How can i test arrow function in mapDispatchToProps of redux by jest

Tags: redux, react-redux, jestjs

How can I test two simple actions in `mapDispatchToProps` of my component.
Command for tests that i'm using is `jest --coverage`, and it tells me to test next lines of my code:

```
export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
---->   rightText: () => dispatch(rightText()),
---->   leftText: () => dispatch(leftText()),
    };
 };
```

How can I write tests to cover these two arrow functions inside `mapDispatchToProps`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to pass a spy to `mapDispatchToProps` and then you can test the functions of returned object:

```
const actionProps = mapDispatchToProps(spy)
// now you can test them
actionProps.rightText()
actionProps.leftText()
```

`rightText()` and `leftText()` should return an object (if it's synchronous). You can also verify the action object in your spy (or it's a [mock](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/mock-functions.html) here) function.

```
const mockDispatch = jest.fn()
const actionProps = mapDispatchToProps(mockDispatch)
actionProps.rightText()
actionProps.leftText()

// now you can verify the actions here
mockDispatch.mock.calls[0][0]
mockDispatch.mock.calls[1][0]
```

And just let you know, you can pass a plain object to `connect`. In your case you can simply:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, {
  rightText,
  leftText
})(Component)
```

Comment: Your answer is very useful but has one little mistake ^^
`mockDispatch.mock.calls[0][0]`
`mockDispatch.mock.calls[0][1]`

should be 

`mockDispatch.mock.calls[0][0]`
`mockDispatch.mock.calls[1][0]`

Thx you very much